# Duplicate Rows in Pyspark DataFrame Dynamic Number of Times Based on Difference between Two Columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe that looks like:

```
+---+----+----+
| id|day1|day2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   2|   4|
|  2|   1|   2|
|  3|   3|   3|
+---+----+----+
```

I want to duplicate each row n number of times where `n = day2 - day1`. The resulting dataframe would look like:

```
+---+----+----+
| id|day1|day2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   2|   4|
|  1|   2|   4|
|  1|   2|   4|
|  2|   1|   2|
|  2|   1|   2|
|  3|   3|   3|
+---+----+----+
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

@F.udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def gen_array(day1, day2):
  return ['' for i in range(day2-day1+1)]

df.withColumn(
  "dup", 
  F.explode(
    gen_array(F.col("day1"), F.col("day2"))
  )
).drop("dup").show()

+---+----+----+
| id|day1|day2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   2|   4|
|  1|   2|   4|
|  1|   2|   4|
|  2|   1|   2|
|  2|   1|   2|
|  3|   3|   3|
+---+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `rdd.flatMap`:

```
df.rdd.flatMap(lambda r: [r] * (r.day2 - r.day1 + 1)).toDF().show()
+---+----+----+
| id|day1|day2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   2|   4|
|  1|   2|   4|
|  1|   2|   4|
|  2|   1|   2|
|  2|   1|   2|
|  3|   3|   3|
+---+----+----+
```